# Венечка или Веничка - как верно написать

Tags: грамматика

Сомневаюсь в написании имени, ведь полным оно звучит как *Вениамин*, да и *Ерофеев Веничка*, как быть?

Answer (score 1):

Если сомневаетесь, пишите Венечка.

*Вопрос № 237893 
Как правильно Юлинька или Юленька? Заранее благодарна.

Juliatuta

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

В существительных с суффиксом -еньк- (-оньк-) начальный гласный суффикса передается на письме буквами Е и О: Юленька.

===

Ответ, конечно, правильный, но следует заметить, что ранее чаще использовалось написание через И. Так, хорошо известна фраза Владимира Жемчужникова «Глупость Сашинькина!», которой он сопровождал почти все рукописи своего брата и будущего соавтора по Козьме Пруткову Александра. Аналогичное написание встречается в прозведениях Пастернака, А. Н. Толстого и многих других авторов.

Полагаю, что именно этим обстоятельством и вызван заданный вопрос.*
©gramota.ru

**Всё сказанное в полной мере относится и к суффиксу "-ечк-".**